# Flink table column name collision between metadata and physical columns

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-flink, amazon-kinesis

We are reading data from a Amazon KDS stream using Apache Flink. The incoming stream records contain a column named "timestamp". We also want to use the approximate arrival time value from the record metadata (which is automatically added by KDS). The metadata key for the approximate arrival time is also named "timestamp". This causes an error when trying to use both columns:

```
CREATE TABLE source_table
(
    `timestamp` VARCHAR(100)
    `approximate_arrival_time` TIMESTAMP(3) METADATA FROM 'timestamp'
)
WITH 
(
    'connector' = 'kinesis',
    ...
);
```

Trying to access data from the table:

```
SELECT * FROM source_table;
```

Results in this error:

```
org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Field names must be unique. Found duplicates: [timestamp]
    at org.apache.flink.table.types.logical.RowType.validateFields(RowType.java:272)
    at org.apache.flink.table.types.logical.RowType.(RowType.java:157)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.connectors.DynamicSourceUtils.createProducedType(DynamicSourceUtils.java:215)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.connectors.DynamicSourceUtils.validateAndApplyMetadata(DynamicSourceUtils.java:443)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.connectors.DynamicSourceUtils.prepareDynamicSource(DynamicSourceUtils.java:158)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.connectors.DynamicSourceUtils.convertSourceToRel(DynamicSourceUtils.java:119)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.schema.CatalogSourceTable.toRel(CatalogSourceTable.java:85)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.toRel(SqlToRelConverter.java:3585)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertIdentifier(SqlToRelConverter.java:2507)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2144)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2093)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2050)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertSelectImpl(SqlToRelConverter.java:663)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertSelect(SqlToRelConverter.java:644)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertQueryRecursive(SqlToRelConverter.java:3438)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertQuery(SqlToRelConverter.java:570)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.calcite.FlinkPlannerImpl.org$apache$flink$table$planner$calcite$FlinkPlannerImpl$$rel(FlinkPlannerImpl.scala:169)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.calcite.FlinkPlannerImpl.rel(FlinkPlannerImpl.scala:161)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.operations.SqlToOperationConverter.toQueryOperation(SqlToOperationConverter.java:989)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.operations.SqlToOperationConverter.convertSqlQuery(SqlToOperationConverter.java:958)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.operations.SqlToOperationConverter.convert(SqlToOperationConverter.java:283)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.ParserImpl.parse(ParserImpl.java:101)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.sqlQuery(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:704)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.flink.sql.AbstractStreamSqlJob.run(AbstractStreamSqlJob.java:102)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.flink.FlinkStreamSqlInterpreter.callInnerSelect(FlinkStreamSqlInterpreter.java:89)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.flink.FlinkSqlInterrpeter.callSelect(FlinkSqlInterrpeter.java:503)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.flink.FlinkSqlInterrpeter.callCommand(FlinkSqlInterrpeter.java:266)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.flink.FlinkSqlInterrpeter.runSqlList(FlinkSqlInterrpeter.java:160)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.flink.FlinkSqlInterrpeter.internalInterpret(FlinkSqlInterrpeter.java:112)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.AbstractInterpreter.interpret(AbstractInterpreter.java:47)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:110)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:852)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:744)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:172)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.AbstractScheduler.runJob(AbstractScheduler.java:132)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.ParallelScheduler.lambda$runJobInScheduler$0(ParallelScheduler.java:46)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```